# Apache Camel GoogleDriveConfiguration not refreshing access token

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel google drive component to move files from a local directory to a Google Drive folder. The Solution works like a dream until the access token expires. I've tried tons of methods to get a new token, none works.
I'm using service account. Reading the keys like this.

```
credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:gdrivebackup.json").getInputStream())
            .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"));
```

Next I'm getting the access token and setting up the GoogleDriveConfiguration

```
  credential.refreshToken();

    String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();

    GoogleDriveConfiguration configuration = new GoogleDriveConfiguration();

    configuration.setClientId(gProperties.getClient_id());
    configuration.setClientSecret(gProperties.getClient_secret());
    configuration.setAccessToken(accessToken);
```

Finally I create a GoogleDriveComponent and add it to the camel context before starting the route

```
CamelContext context = super.getContext();
    GoogleDriveComponent component = new GoogleDriveComponent(context);
    component.setConfiguration(configuration);

    context.addComponent("google-drive", component);


    from("quartz://myTimer?cron={{quartz.timer}}")
            .setProperty("ClientID", constant(gProperties.getClient_id()))
            .setProperty("ClientSecret", constant(gProperties.getClient_secret()))
            .setProperty("ParentID", constant(gProperties.getParent_id()))
            .setProperty("FilePath", constant(gProperties.getUpload_file_path()))
            .setProperty("Cred", method("authBean", "getAccessCredential"))
            .process(bkpFile)
            .to("google-drive://drive-files/insert")
            .log("Upload Successful")
            .end();
```

In the processor (bkpFile) I'm repeating above steps to try refresh the token before uploading the file as below

```
UPLOAD_FILE = new java.io.File(exchange.getProperty("FilePath").toString());

    System.out.println("PATH: "+exchange.getProperty("FilePath"));
    System.out.println("Parent ID: "+exchange.getProperty("ParentID").toString());

    ParentReference parRef=new ParentReference();
    parRef.setId(exchange.getProperty("ParentID").toString());
    List<ParentReference> parents=new ArrayList<>();
    parents.add(parRef);

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());
    fileMetadata.setParents(parents);

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, UPLOAD_FILE);
    final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();

    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.content", fileMetadata);
    headers.put("CamelGoogleDrive.mediaContent", mediaContent);
    exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
```

Any help or advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplicity of Apache Camel can sometimes have you run around in circles. Anyways I've learned the hard way. It turned out that this was the only line of code needed to resolve all my authentication mysteries.

```
.to("google-drive://drive-files/insert?serviceAccountKey=classpath:gdrivebackup.json&scopes={{mygoogle.scopes}}")
```

After this I had to get rid of a tonne of garbage code I wasted lots of time debugging